# React Native (flexDirection: "row") not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason when I'm trying to align the contents of the Card which is the Image and Card.Title it will always align it like a column, the two won't go next to each other.

However, if I put the flexDirection: "row" in the modal container (which contains these two cards) it puts the cards side by side as it should. Why would it not work on the contents of the card itself?

Thanks

```
      <Provider>
        <Portal>
          <Modal Modal visible={themeVisible} onDismiss={hideThemeModal} contentContainerStyle={modalStyle}>

            <Card containerStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#3D3D3D', margin: 0, padding: 0, borderWidth: 0, elevation: 0, borderColor: '#212121' }}>
              <Card.Title style={{ color: '#FFFFFF', marginBottom: 0, fontSize: 25, marginTop: 10 }} >Theme Selection</Card.Title>
              <Text style={{ color: '#AAAAAA', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }} >Thanks for supporting Fitness!</Text>
            </Card>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={hideThemeModal}>
              <Card containerStyle={{ flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: '#3D3D3D', marginTop: 10, paddingBottom: 30, padding: 30, borderWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1, elevation: 0, borderColor: '#212121' }}>
                <Image style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} source={require('./assets/yellow-dark.png')} />
                <Card.Title style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }} >Yellow / Dark</Card.Title>
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>

          </Modal>
        </Portal>
      </Provider>
```

Tried float: left, flexdirection, inline-block, etc no change

Here is the styles for modalStyle and the safeareaview style

```
const modalStyle = {
  backgroundColor: '#3D3D3D',
  padding: 20,
  margin: 35,
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 7.5,
  borderColor: '#F3AF21',
};
```

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: "flex",
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#181818',
  },
});
```

Comment: Have you tried giving - display: 'flex' ?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra yeah the display:flex is given to the modals through the View stylesheet

Comment: I think you should give it a try in <Card containerStyle

Comment: @SiddharthMishra tried before, tried again to double check but still no luck

Comment: Are you using react-native-elements ?

Comment: @SiddharthMishra yep, importing Card along others with react-native-elements

Comment: Replace container style with wrapperStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Card component has 2 props for styling. `containerStyle` is used to style the outer container while `wrapperStyle` for inner container. In your code you should replace containerStyle with wrapperStyle

```
<Card wrapperStyle={{ flexDirection: "row", backgroundColor: '#3D3D3D', marginTop: 10, paddingBottom: 30, padding: 30, borderWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 1, borderBottomWidth: 1, elevation: 0, borderColor: '#212121' }}>
       <Image style={{ width: 25, height: 25 }} source={require('./assets/yellow-dark.png')} />
       <Card.Title style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }} >Yellow / Dark</Card.Title>
</Card>
```

**Note**: You can adjust the other attributes in both the styles as per your need.